# I need to search for the customer's id by name

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search for the customer's id by name
Is taking the first record from the bank

I believe the problem is in the structure of SQL

I need to find a way to get the customer's id through the name passed in the form

**I'm passing the name on the form**

**This is VIEW**

```
 <div id="hid_cpf" class="col-xs-7">
                <span>Nome do fornecedor</span>
                <?php if ($nome != null) { ?>
                    <input type="text" id="nome_forn" name="nome_forn" value="<?php echo $nome ?>">    
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <input type="text" id="nome_forn" name="nome_forn" onblur="verificaNomeExists(this) "class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="on">
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Here I am doing the search, but it is bringing the first record from the database

**THIS IS MODEL**

```
    ////Veficar matrícula cadastro.
 function verificaNome($nome) {

    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pessoa_fisica WHERE nome = '$nome' AND id_pessoa_fisica");

    //$sql2 = $this->db->query("SELECT matricula FROM cliente WHERE profissao = 'countmatricula'");

    //$sql3 = $this->db->query("SELECT id_client_forn FROM cadastro WHERE id_forn == '' ");
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT c.id_cadastro, pf.nome, id_pessoa, id_endereco, id_pessoa_fisica, email, telefone FROM cadastro c, pessoa_fisica pf 
    WHERE pf.nome = '$nome' " );

    $sql2 = $this->db->query("SELECT c.id_cadastro, pf.nome, id_pessoa, id_endereco, id_pessoa_fisica, email, telefone FROM cadastro c, pessoa_fisica pf 
    WHERE pf.nome = '$nome' " );


    //$sql3 = $this->db->query("SELECT matricula FROM cliente WHERE matricula = 'contmatricula");

    if (count($sql->result()) >= '1') {

        //Dados do cliente/cadastro
        $cliente = $sql->result();
        /*
        //Dados dos bancos
        $banco = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM dados_bancarios
         LEFT JOIN banco ON banco.id_banco=dados_bancarios.id_banco
         WHERE dados_bancarios.id_cadastro="'. $cliente[0]->id_cadastro . '"');
        */

        //Dados Pessoa

        $sqlPessoa = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM pessoa_fisica WHERE id_pessoa_fisica= "' . $cliente[0]->id_pessoa . '"');
        $pessoa = $sqlPessoa->result();
        //

        //Dados Endereço

        $sqlEndereco = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM endereco WHERE id_endereco= "' . $cliente[0]->id_endereco . '"');
        $endereco = $sqlEndereco->result();


        //Array de retorno com os dados
        $dados = [
            'cliente' => isset($cliente[0]) ? $cliente[0] : [],
            //'bancos' => $banco->result(),
            'pessoa' => isset($pessoa[0]) ? $pessoa[0] : [],
            'endereco' => isset($endereco[0]) ? $endereco[0] : []
            //'contatos' => $contatos
            //'anexos' => $anexos,
            //'atendimentos' => $atendimentos
            //'historicos' => $historicos
        ];

        return $dados;

    } else {
        return $sql2->result();
        //return $sql3->result();


    }
}
```

**THIS IS CONTROLLER**

```
//Verificar nome.
        function verificaNomeExists() {
            $nome = $this->input->post('nome');
            $res = $this->compras_m->verificaNome($nome);

            if (isset($res['cliente']->nome) && $res['cliente']->nome === $nome) {
                echo json_encode($res, true);
                } else {
                    echo "0";
                }
        }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: It should be ```SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = ?;``` replacing '?' using the bind method described by @tadman.
But this would require that you get the exact same name from your form as it exists in your database. Also, you have to make sure making the ```name```-field at least unique in your table if not making it primary key.

Comment: @Danaq Watch those quotes. Backticks on column names, and no quotes around placeholders.

Comment: Can you explain how to use the method? @tadman

Comment: sure, thanks @tadman

Comment: I don't know how to use this method
 tadman

Comment: Which database driver are you using here? It's not clear from your code.

Comment: I'm using msqli

Comment: Welcome to your new friend [`bind_param`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 1):

```php
$this->db = new mysqli(SQL_HOST, SQL_DBUSER, SQL_DBPASS, SQL_DBNAME);

// validate input before using values from outside

$sql = 'SELECT
           `id`
        FROM
            `users`
        WHERE
            `name` = ?';

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // do stuff here with $result
}
```

The `'s'` in the `bind_param()`-method indicated that a string is bound.
This method assumes that your `db` class attribute was initialized using mysqli.

It would be a better solution to separate the creation of the db-connection into another class implementing the singleton pattern.

**Attention:**
This would require that you get the exact same name from your form as it exists in your database. Also, you have to make sure to make the name-field at least unique in your table if not making it a primary key.